# "ng new app" creates project but with some errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On running `ng new app`, my directory for app with angular files and folders seems to be created but with a stack which I am sharing below:

```
$ ng new music
installing ng
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
  create src\app\app.component.css
  create src\app\app.component.html
  create src\app\app.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\app.component.ts
  create src\app\app.module.ts
  create src\assets\.gitkeep
  create src\environments\environment.prod.ts
  create src\environments\environment.ts
  create src\favicon.ico
  create src\index.html
  create src\main.ts
  create src\polyfills.ts
  create src\styles.css
  create src\test.ts
  create src\tsconfig.app.json
  create src\tsconfig.spec.json
  create src\typings.d.ts
  create .angular-cli.json
  create e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts
  create e2e\app.po.ts
  create e2e\tsconfig.e2e.json
  create .gitignore
  create karma.conf.js
  create package.json
  create protractor.conf.js
  create tsconfig.json
  create tslint.json
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
spawn UNKNOWN
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:143:15)
    at Object.exports.exec (child_process.js:103:18)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\npm-install.js:15:29
    at Class.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\npm-install.js:13:16)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\init.js:83:35
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2373:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I am not able to figure out why this occurs. The project seems to be running fine without any problem but why this error.

**Versions:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.9.5
npm: 3.10.10
os: win32 x64
```

Comment: Perhaps you should see if this is an [open issue on the project repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues) and, if not, create one? They will want to know things like version (of the CLI, Node and NPM) and platform, too.

Comment: I have created a thread with #5232. Thanks.

Comment: That version is quite a way behind; have you tried updating? For convenience: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5232

Comment: @AakashThakur What's your `ng --version` output when run in the same directory where you tried `ng new`?

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli is no longer supported use the @angular/cli instead :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```